# GIDSignIn with UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift, google-oauth

Google's docs say that if "the class that implements GIDSignInUIDelegate is not a subclass of UIViewController, implement the signInWillDispatch:error:, signIn:presentViewController:, and signIn:dismissViewController: methods of the GIDSignInUIDelegate protocol". I'm using a `UITableViewController`.

How do I use these methods with a `UITableViewController` (and with a `UISwitch`)? Do I implement those methods in my `appDel` or view controller? So much confusion!!!!!

Comment: `signIn:presentViewController:` and `signIn:dismissViewController:` are not relevant for iOS 11 and higher as they never get called. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57112433/1433612

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately `UITableViewController` is itself a subclass of `UIViewController` so you don't need to do anything special, just set your `UITableViewController` as the delegate for Google Sign-in.

Comment: `UITableViewController` is subclass of  `UIViewController` and not sub-view