# GIDSignInUIDelegate Methods to getting called

Tags: ios, google-signin

I have a view controller on a navigation stack (2nd child).

Controller is setup as GIDSignInDelegate and GIDSignInUIDelegate.

After triggering sign-in, every delegate method expected to be called, is called, except for:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!)
```

and

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!)
```

Note that in `viewDidLoad` I have assigned the view controller to be the delegate and ui delegate.

Also, after dismissing the Google Sign-In view, my current view controller is automatically popped off the navigation stack (?????)

What is causing this?

Comment: How did you implement the `dismiss` delegate function?? You may have made something wrong in it, like dismissing the view that presented the current view controller

Comment: The dismiss delegate function is -- not -- getting called, at all.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is occurring on iOS 11 and higher then I found this explanation in the changelog document of the framework: https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn/changelog

Entry from 2017-10-17 -- v4.1.1 states:

> Fixes an issue that GIDSignInUIDelegate's signInWillDispatch:error: was
>   not called on iOS 11. Please note that it is intended that neither
>   signIn:presentViewController: nor signIn:dimissViewController: is called
>   on iOS 11 because SFAuthenticationSession is not presented by the app's view
>   controller.

According to the above explanation `signInWillDispatch:error` is indeed called, but `signIn:presentViewController:` and `signIn:dimissViewController:` are **intentionally** not called because the underlying `SFAuthenticationSession` presents and dismisses sign-in flow through private API rendering the two callback methods useless. I suppose these methods are remaining in the `GIDSignInUIDelegate` protocol solely for the sake of backwards compatibility with iOS 10 where `SFAuthenticationSession` was not used and the sign in flow could be presented and dismissed from a particular view controller.

However even though the two methods never get called on iOS 11 and higher they still need to be implemented when the delegate object is not a subclass of `UIViewController`, otherwise the app will crash. Obviously it's not very logical to have methods implemented which do nothing...

On a side note, Google could do a better job at updating their documentation because now it is rather misleading: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/protocol_g_i_d_sign_in_u_i_delegate-p#a2b265097a3c78e7f82d57b2ccda11c39