# Firebase Google Sign In (iOS) - GIDSignInUIDelegate methods never called

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4

Using Firebase Auth to sign in with Google. I can successfully sign in and the sign didSignInForUser method is called in the AppDelgate class, but the corresponding UI delegate method is never called.
Any ideas why the uiDelegate method is not called in the UIViewController?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
}

// This method is never called
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    // Initialize sign-in
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "CLIENT_ID"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}

// This is called in AppDelagte on successful sign in
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I suppose you're running iOS 11 or later. I do not see any `GIDSignInUIDelegate` method implementations in your code. `didSignInForUser` is a `GIDSignInDelegate` method. But if you do implement `GIDSignInUIDelegate` and get no callbacks here is why.

`signInWillDispatch:error:` should indeed get called. But probably your issue is in `signIn:presentViewController:` and `signIn:dimissViewController:`. These two methods are intentionally not called because the underlying `SFAuthenticationSession` presents the sign-in flow by the private API which is not accessible to developers, therefore those callbacks are impossible.

See my full answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57112433/1433612